# AttributeError: 'TranslationServiceClient' object has no attribute 'translate_document'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate


def translate_document(project_id: str, file_path: str):

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "us-central1"

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Supported file types: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    with open(file_path, "rb") as document:
        document_content = document.read()

    document_input_config = {
        "content": document_content,
        "mime_type": "application/pdf",
    }

    response = client.translate_document(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "target_language_code": "fr-FR",
            "document_input_config": document_input_config,
        }
    )

    # To view translated document, write `response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs` to file.
    # If not provided in the TranslationRequest, the translated file will only be returned through a byte-stream
    # and its output mime type will be the same as the input file's mime type
    print("Response: Detected Language Code - {}".format(response.document_translation.detected_language_code))
```

Comment: I want to translate pdf as input document. getting the above mentioned issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. We need _full_ error messages, with context. Please read [ask].